# In google colab with matplotlib, inline output is different from image download

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, inline

In google colab with matplotlib, inline output is different from image download.

It seems like the inline backend always uses an autolayout feature even though no tight or constrained layout is enabled. I couldn't find any suitable answers in my research so far...

Here the Code sample from matplotlib homepage:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()

rect = fig.patch  # a rectangle instance
rect.set_facecolor('lightgoldenrodyellow')

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4])

rect = ax1.patch
rect.set_facecolor('lightslategray')

ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:red', labelrotation=45, labelsize=16)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', color='tab:green', size=25, width=3)

plt.show()

fig.savefig('figure_margins_orig.png')
```

Below are the corresponding images.

Used backend and matplotlib version:[image]

Wrong image with the inline backend:[image]

Expected image with the savefig backend:[image]

I have tried to set the `layout=None` at the `plt.figure` creation or use another command `fig.subplots_adjust` to determine the position and the size of the axes manually without resizing the figure background.

But always the same result: the inline generated image ignores the manual settings but the downloaded image with `fig.savefig` is always correct

Unfortunately, the inline output in a colab cell is not a WYSIWYG process for manual layout settings, or am I wrong here?

Comment: Did you try setting autolayout in plt.rc('figure', autolayout=True) to False?

Comment: Yes i tried to set the runtime configuration parameter to 'plt.rc('figure', autolayout=False) ' at the start of the script before I generate the figure but unfortunately there was the same wrong result!